# Scala. Play: get data and test result

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have a sql query which returns two rows and columns values. I want to get that data and check if its empty or not. How can i do that?
I am a fresh man to scala with playframework can any one please help me here.
I have used model class to store the response and show in json format but i want to know how to check the condition for the data.

```
val query= s""" select * from table"""

override def map2Object(implicit map: Map[String, Any]): HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck = {
  HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck(str("roleName"), oint("PersonID"))
}
```

Now i want to know how to check the condition whether the sql return empty or true data ad i want to execute the next sql query.

SO I have tried some ways in which i get error in type casting:

```
override val singleQuery = s"""select * from Sitable"""
override val allQuery= s"""select * from Sitable1"""
override def map2Object(implicit map: Map[String, Any]): HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck = {
  HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck(str("roleName"), oint("PersonID"))
}

def map2ObjectBilling(implicit map: Map[String, Any]): HierarchyEntryBilling = {
  HierarchyEntryBilling(str("Name"), str("Provider"), oint("Year"), 
    ostr("Month"), ostr("Status"), ostr("ProviderType"))
}

def getAll(implicit loginName: String): Future[Seq[HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck]] = {
  doQueryIgnoreRowErrors(allQuery, "loginName" -> loginName)

  result.map {
    if (map2Object.roleName !="" && map2Object.PersonID.isEmpty) {
      "error"
    } else {
      getOnetask()
    }  //GEtting error with unit type cannot resolve future[seq[]]
  }

  def getOnetask(): Future[Seq[HierarchyEntryBilling]] = {
    doQueryIgnoreRowErrors(singleQuery)
  } //Getting error with type unit does not confirm Future[Seq[]]
```

.// doQueryignore errors signature=>

```
  protected def doQueryIgnoreRowErrors(query: String, args: NamedParameter*) 
   = {

 logger.debug(s"SQL: $query, args: $args")

 TimedFuture(actualityTimeout) {
  queryHandler.doQuery(query, args: _*) map { list =>
    // ignore mapping errors of specific rows
    list.flatten
   }
  } flatMap {
  case scala.util.Success(s) => Future.successful(s)
  case Failure(ex) if ex.isInstanceOf[SQLException] &&
    ex.getMessage == "The executeQuery method must return a result set." => 
  Future.successful(Nil)
  case Failure(fail)         =>
    Future.failed(fail)
```

Comment: Try do a bit of research around play/slick examples like:  https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/tree/master/samples/basic Hope that helps .. also there is a number of options you get extract data with play, I would assume you are using slick

Comment: its definitely not me:) but I would suspect that the reason that is very basic question, but sometimes people downvote with no reason. Are you able to read data from table at all ??

Comment: @Pavel, Sorry really i dint mean you,  i was asking generally, and For reading data from table? Yes , I mapped that to an object and i am able to display the data from two tables separately but still i am not able to check for the condition to satisfy, I am most probably getting error with type casting!

Comment: So, it would be easy for people to understand your question if you would provide code samples etc

Comment: Please add error message to the question body

Comment: I would assume map2ObjectBilling is a controller method or this is with in console app?

Comment: Please read next docs: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html I would assume its going to help you with Futures. its definitely trivial conversion issue.

Comment: @Pavel, i tried many options but its not working , can you please help me in sorting out this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do check signature for your doQueryIgnoreRowErrors method
I would suspect it should be something like:

```
 def doQueryIgnoreRowErrors(sql: String, name: String): Future[Seq[HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck]] = {
    // next lines instead of calling data sources
    Future[Seq[HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck]] {
      List(HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck(1, "Data"))
    }
  }
```

I would assume you are getting result like:

```
    def getAll(implicit loginName: String): Future[Seq[HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck]] = {

val result = doQueryIgnoreRowErrors(allQuery, "loginName")
.. 
}
```

Let me know if you are still struggling with this.

Comment: I have given my complete code which i tried and were i need help, so can you please see this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881981/i-need-help-in-fetching-the-data-from-sql-and-test-the-result-using-conditions-a " and try to help in me in the part were i need to call the method and execute the second query

Comment: getOnetask will always throw an error, you have to return Future from doQueryIgnoreRowErrors. So its either you need to change getOnetask to use queryHandler or rewrite  doQueryIgnoreRowErrors

Comment: I have removed the getonetask actually i dint mention that method name in routes so i removed it. So i have given my complete code try in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46881981/i-need-help-in-fetching-the-data-from-sql-and-test-the-result-using-conditions-a" , can you plese guide me in that.

Comment: well, its all take time, I would rather take some training, you could struggle for long time if you don't understand basic concepts and have very little practice.. question you are asking very basic

Comment: Yes Thanks i would definitely need it, Can you just some ways on scala training , till now i have just gone through some scala.org and googling. IS there any good resource for me to dirt my hands so i could become well programmer

Comment: scala -> coursera let this be starting point, all you need to know, this will take 6 months or so, gitHub or tools separate training, you can try udemy  quite cheep online courses, but for you do more practice and own project along the way. but all this in the context you already have some degree in computer science

Comment: Thanks for your kind knowledge share on scala , let me do this as a daily practice.