# How to fetch the data from sql and test the result using if conditions using scala with playframework?

Tags: sql-server, scala, playframework

I have one controller =>

```
   @Singleton
   class NewBillingMonthController @Inject() (implicit cacheService: 
   CacheService, repository: NewBillingRoleRepository, contexts: Contexts,
  securityService: SecurityService) extends BaseController {
  def getAll(implicit queryParams: QueryParams): Action[AnyContent] = 
  securityService.authenticate() { implicit request =>
  withErrorRecovery { req =>
  toJson {
    repository.getAll(request.user.loginName)
     repository.getUser()
      }
```

// This controller calls the respository were i have a sql defined 
This show the repository=> newBillingRepository.scala=>

```
   class NewBillingRoleRepository @Inject() (val queryHandler: 
   QueryHandler, val contexts: Contexts, val configurationService: 
   ConfigurationService)
   extends Repository[HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck] {
   override val allQuery = s"""
                         select users from tble """
    override def map2Object(implicit map: Map[String, Any]): 
   HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck = {
  HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck(str("roleName"), oint("PersonID"))}

 def getAll(implicit loginName: String): 
 Future[Seq[HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck]] = {
 doQueryIgnoreRowErrors(allQuery, "loginName" -> loginName) }
```

another repo:

```
  class UserNewBillingRepository @Inject() (val queryHandler: QueryHandler, 
  val contexts: Contexts, val configurationService: ConfigurationService)
  extends Repository[HierarchyEntryBilling] {
   override val allQuery= s"""select * from SiACPManageBillingMonth"""


  def getrepo():Future[Seq[HierarchyEntryBilling]]= {
 doQueryIgnoreRowErrors(allQuery)
  }


  override def map2Object(implicit map: Map[String, Any]): 
 HierarchyEntryBilling = {

  HierarchyEntryBilling(str("Name"), str("Provider"), oint("Year"), 
  ostr("Month"), ostr("Status"), ostr("ProviderType"))
```

My issuse i want to know how to fetch the data from 1st sql and test the result for empty or not and execute the second query?

Comment: @Scalausers, can you please help me on this problem, i am trying hard but i need some solution for this task , seriously i am stuck in this work for past 2 weeks, please help !!

Comment: @users, can you pls guide me on this task